# Read the data of CSV file inside Zip File without extracting the contents in Matlab

Tags: matlab, zip, unzip

I have number of Zip Files `{'File1.zip', 'File2.zip', 'File3.zip',..., 'FileN.zip'}` in which each zip file contains a `Data.csv` file. I want to read the data in `'Data.csv'` of each Zip file without having to extract the Zip files' contents. Is this possible..?

Comment: You can extract the file with the `unzip` command, read it, and delete it later if you don't want it.

Comment: My thought is instead of extracting or deleting....whether we can directly read the contents using actxserver application or java components in matlab....

Comment: That's an idea. You should edit the question to include this possible method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly Winzip / 7zip / Winrar do not have COM interface component which can invoke directly unlike word, excel an other application.

Hence @Java is appropriate

Idea is don't extract files physically , however create absolute path of file such that windows consider as physical presence of File (similar to ~tmp file)

here the code

```
zipFilename = 'Ex.zip';
zipJavaFile  = java.io.File(zipFilename);
```

% Create a Java ZipFile

```
 zipFile = org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile(zipJavaFile);
```

% Extract the entries from the ZipFile.

```
 entries = zipFile.getEntries;
 cnt = 1;
```

% Get Zip File Paths

```
 while entries.hasNext
   tempObj = entries.nextElement;
   file{cnt,1} = tempObj.getName.toCharArray';
   cnt = cnt+ 1;
 end
```

% Extract File Name

```
 ind = regexp(file,'$*.csv$');
 ind = find(~cellfun(@isempty,ind));  % Find Non Empty Cell Index
 file = file(ind);
```

% Create Absolute Path so that Windows consider as Directory

```
  file = cellfun(@(x) fullfile('.',x),file,'UniformOutput',false);
```

% Now Operate Any thing on File.

Comment: It is may be java version dependent but I have to use `while entries.hasMoreElements` instead of `while entries.hasNext` to get it to work. Nice trick otherwise. Don't forget to mention to **close** the java zipfile after use (`zipFile.close`) or it will be locked until you close Matlab.